# c# How to capture data accordingly

Tags: c#, string

Currently, I am receiving strings of data (RxString) from a serial port. Such as

```
T 22 27.0
T 22 27.0
T 21 25.0
T 22 26.8
```

line by line..

First, I tried to split the string to extract the middle number out for comparison purpose.

```
string[] number = RxString.Split(' ');
string unit = split[1];
```

then I do the comparison by

```
int count = 0;
string x = "";
if (x == unit)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
            x = unit;
        }
        if (count == 4)
        {
            StreamWriter MyStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\acer\Documents\Data3.txt", true);  //True tell SW to append to file instead of overwriting
            MyStreamWriter.Write(time + "      " + RxString + "\r\n");  //Write time + string
            MyStreamWriter.Flush();
            MyStreamWriter.Close();
            count = 0;  //reset count
        }
```

What I expect is:

1. I need to capture all incoming data into a txt file.
2. For the 4 identical data "sensed", I would need to do some editing to the format of the data such as just record the data without the time stamp.

Meaning if incoming data were:

```
T 22 24.0
T 22 24.0
T 22 24.0
T 22 24.0
T 23 26.7
T 20 25.0
```

Then what should appear in my .txt file is

```
T 22 24.0
T 22 24.0
T 22 24.0
T 22 24.0
10:24:20 T 23 26.7
10:24 40 T 20 25.0
```

The problem is:

1. This only captured the 4th incoming data, the rest of the data were missing.. I understand I should add the streamwriter code but when i tried to copy and paste them into the first if-else loop, the system stop running.
2. If i have the streamwriter coding placed outside all the if-else/if loop, the system simply captured all data into the txt file..

Is there a better way to implement the streamwriter function?

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff");
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();

        string[] split = RxString.Split('.');  //split RxString at '.'
        string dp = split[1];                 //dp contains digit behind '.'
        Char c = dp[0];                      //c = first decimal place
        split[1] = c.ToString();
        RxString = split[0] + "." + split[1];  //Re-combine Rxstring

        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

        string[] number = RxString.Split(' ');
        string unit = split[1];

        if (x == unit)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
            x = unit;
        }
        if (count == 4)
        {

            StreamWriter MyStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\acer\Documents\Data3.txt", true);  //True tell SW to append to file instead of overwriting
            MyStreamWriter.Write(time + "      " + RxString + "\r\n");  //Write time + string
            MyStreamWriter.Flush();
            MyStreamWriter.Close();
            count = 0;  //reset count
        }
```

Comment: Using `File.AppendAllText(...)` is much cleaner than mucking around with streams.

Comment: @Sachu No.. any advice?

Comment: @Sachu one shot as in? Rxstring actually represent 1 line tho..

Comment: @Sachu oh.. I'm receiving it through a serial port.. the port will feed the sys with data

Comment: @Enigmativity you mean this?    File.AppendAllText("C:\Users\acer\Documents\Data3.txt", time + "      " + RxString + "\r\n");

Comment: @Athena is it possible to post the full function code?

Comment: @Sachu Yup! posted the DataReceived portion

Comment: @Athena - Yes, that's what I mean. Can you please let us know what the expected output would look like given your input?

Comment: @Athena - According to the docs `serialPort1.ReadLine()` reads only to the next new line and stops. If you think you're reading more than one line you need a loop. It also appears as if you need to respond to a timeout exception to know when there is no data left. I'd read the docs if I were you and see if that helps - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> > 1. I need to capture all incoming data into a txt file.

Then the file needs to be kept open, and for every record of your RxString, you need to write to the opened stream;

> > 2. For the 4 identical data "sensed", I would need to do some editing to the format of the data such as just record the data without the time stamp.

Your if/else logic seems ok except for the stream writer, which is opened and closed too often.

IO process is very expensive, open/close/flush would consume CPU time. Suggest put the IO persistence onto a separate thread so that your serial port reading is not blocked as otherwise you would probably lose data.

You can try [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for the data logging.